How to compare values in excel and get OK or KO
I have an Excel with the following values in a row:
United States | 30 | 38 | 35
Italy         | 10 | 10 | 11

Then I have another row with some cells with different values:
United States | 30 | 38 | 34
Italy         | 10 | 12 | 11

I need to build a formula in excel which in the first step finds "United States" and "Italy", then compare every column. If the value matches I have to get "OK", otherwise "KO".
Taking the example above:
United States | 30 | 38 | 35 | United States | 30 | 38 | 34  | OK | OK | KO

Italy         | 10 | 10 | 11 | Italy         | 10 | 12 | 11  | OK | KO | OK


As a formula?  No way.  You may be able to do this with VBA.

As a direct match if the ranges are static and always in the same place you could use =IF($B$1:$D$1=$B$5:$D$5,"OK","KO") where B1:D1 is your first US figures and B5:D5 are the second US figures.  Could you edit your question and explain more about where the data is located?  Might the first set be in row 1 starting in column A, and the second set  in row 5000 starting in column ZY?  Will they always be three sets of numbers?

This is the formula:
=LET(fil,FILTER(A1:D4,A1:A4="United States"),
res,DROP(IF(TAKE(fil,1)=DROP(fil,1),"OK","KO"),,1),
HSTACK(TOROW(fil),res))

Change the country name for other country
The result looks like


If you have a data, like you have shown, there could be some other country names as well following the other two, then you should do it in this order to make it more dynamic with one single dynamic array formula :


=LET(
     _Sorted, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(SORT(A1:D5,,-1)),8),
     _Logic, IF(DROP(TAKE(_Sorted,,4)=DROP(_Sorted,,4),,1),"OK","KO"),
     IFNA(HSTACK(_Sorted,_Logic),""))



With main logic: iterate over rows for each county comparing the subsequent rows to the first row
is_ok, LAMBDA(arr,
  HSTACK("", DROP(IF(TAKE(arr, 1) = TAKE(arr, -1), "OK", "KO"), , 1))
)

added option for vertical or horizontal stacking for fun:
=LET(
    data, A1:D100,
    country, INDEX(data, , 1),
    stack_horizontally, FALSE,
    u_countries, UNIQUE(FILTER(country, country <> "")),
    is_ok, LAMBDA(arr, HSTACK("", DROP(IF(TAKE(arr, 1) = TAKE(arr, -1), "OK", "KO"), , 1))),
    stack_rows_for_country, LAMBDA(acc, cur,
        LET(
            filtered, FILTER(data, country = cur),
            stacked, DROP(
                REDUCE(
                    "stack filtered rows with OK rows",
                    SEQUENCE(ROWS(filtered)),
                    LAMBDA(acc_ok, r,
                        VSTACK(
                            acc_ok,
                            IF(
                                r = 1,
                                INDEX(filtered, r, ),
                                VSTACK(INDEX(filtered, r, ), is_ok(TAKE(filtered, r)))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                1
            ),
            VSTACK(acc, IF(stack_horizontally, TOROW(stacked), stacked))
        )
    ),
    counry_rows, DROP(REDUCE("stack rows for country", u_countries, stack_rows_for_country), 1),
    counry_rows
)


